# Moderator edit invalidated an answer

Tags: discussion, editing

Feeling a bit hesitant rolling back an edit by a moderator, but on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205200/force-user-to-remove-usb-token) , [this edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/revisions/205200/4) by a moderator invalidates [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/205215).

My understanding across SE is that such edits are not okay (have rolled back a fair number of them which always got approved) and that a new question should be asked instead if necessary, is this different on this specific SE or should that edit get rolled back?

Answer (score 5):

Where possible, we encourage the OP to include clarifying comments onto their post, or just edit them in. This goes not only for mods but for anyone with edit permissions.

And this is actually the case across most of SE.

Yes, we want to ensure the answers are valid for future visitors, but we also want them to be valid for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

The reason I edited it was to include the details in the comments that the answer did not consider. Hence the need for an edit to the question to make sure that answers are in scope of the context of the question.

This happens from time to time and is the primary reason why we push so hard for posters to add the details in their Questions and not leave them in the comments.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it's totally okay to invalidate answers through comments to the question on security.SE . Just so you know, on the rest of SE the idea is that a question isn't just about the person who asked the question, but the question should be useful for everybody else as well. If you ask the wrong question (which is on-topic for the site) and somebody answers the question correctly then that's a valid Q&A pair which might be useful and editing it to invalidate the answer is something moderators step in to revert.

Comment: That's not what I said at all.